# How to return the value of the variable in the condition?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, return, return-value

Code must return value of variable if value equal 42.
I have two idea. As a variant to choose?

```rb
# variant A
if foo == 42
  return foo
end

# variant B    
if foo == 42
  return 42
end
```

Comment: I recommend the first way without any rendundancies

Comment: Both options are 100% equivalent. Which one to use is up to your personal style and probably the style of the surrounding code.

Answer (score 0):

if foo==42
  foo
end

This will do.